# Jquery Internet Explorer/Edge toggleClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So I made this horizontal menu which has a div slide from underneath it when clicked. Everything works fine, except Internet Explorer and Edge fold out all submenus when any of the items with a submenu is clicked. I have seen that there are can be some compatibility issues with toggle()/toggleClass() but have not found a solution that worked yet. Any ideas?

Js:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
        $('.info-menu').click(function(){
            // Append proper class to generic submenu name.
            var menuNumber = this.classList[1];
            var menuToggle = '.top-sub-nav-fixed.' + menuNumber;
            // If other sub menu item is active, toggle active
            $('.top-sub-nav-fixed').each(function (){
               if (typeof this.classList[2] != 'undefined' && this.classList[1] != menuNumber ) {
                   $(this).toggleClass('active');
               }
            });
            // Toggle appropriate menu item
            $(menuToggle).toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Fiddle here: [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61fwu81a/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty straightforward: instead of using `toggleClass()` inside of the `each()` statement using `removeClass()` did the trick. 
For some reason IE sets all DIVs to active (as opposed to webkit or gecko based browsers) when using `toggleClass()` in this function.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.info-menu').click(function(){
        // Append proper class to generic submenu name.
        var menuNumber = this.classList[1];
        var menuToggle = '.top-sub-nav-fixed.' + menuNumber;
        // If other sub menu item is active, toggle active
        $('.top-sub-nav-fixed').each(function (){
           if (typeof this.classList[2] != 'undefined' && this.classList[1] != menuNumber ) {
               $(this).removeClass('active');
           }
        });
        // Toggle appropriate menu item
        $(menuToggle).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```